# Subract a random number from a variable, store this new value, and repeat the process until it reaches 0?

Tags: javascript

Trying to make a hp bar go down from 200 to 0 by constantly subracting the randomized number, but I can only manage to store the new value once. Then if I click on the button which calls the function, it subtracts from 200 again and not the previous stored value. How do I fix this? Going mad over here.

Here's my javascript:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    document.getElementById("hpLeft1").innerHTML= "200/200";
    document.getElementById("hpLeft2").innerHTML = "200/200";
};

var myHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 + 1);
var dragonHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 + 1);
var playerHitpoints, dragonHitpoints = 200;


function play() {

    var myHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 + 1);
    var dragonHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 + 1);

    dragonHitpoints -= dragonHit;
    playerHitpoints -= myHit;

    document.getElementById("DragonHit").innerHTML = dragonHit;
    document.getElementById("MyHit").innerHTML = myHit;

    document.getElementById("hpLeft1").innerHTML = dragonHitpoints + "/200";
    document.getElementById("hpLeft2").innerHTML = playerHitpoints + "/200";
}
```

Comment: Where is the subtraction?

Comment: @Barmar 'var dragonHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 + 1);' needs to be subtracted from 'var dragonHitpoints = 200;' and be stored into 'var storeDragon'

Comment: That's my point. Why aren't you subtracting it if that's what you want to do?

Comment: Cuz I'm really dumb and didn't think of the obvious thing to do haha

Comment: @Barmar look at my updated code, why is playerHitpoints being displayed as NaN but the dragonHitpoints isn't?

Comment: You never initialized `playerHitPoints` to 200.

Comment: `var playerHitPoints = 200, dragonHitPoints = 200;`

Comment: Thought I declared both playerHitpoints and dragonHitpoints as 200? or does it only count the last one written?

Comment: You declared both variables, but you only initialized the second one. The first one has no `= 200`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to update the values of `dragonHitpoints` and `playerHitpoints`.

```
function play() {
  var myHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 + 1);
  var dragonHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 + 1);

  // Update the dragon's HP
  dragonHitpoints -= dragonHit;
  // Update the player's HP
  playerHitpoints -= myHit;      

  document.getElementById("DragonHit").innerHTML = dragonHit;
  document.getElementById("MyHit").innerHTML = myHit;

  document.getElementById("hpLeft1").innerHTML = dragonHitpoints + "/200";
  document.getElementById("hpLeft2").innerHTML = playerHitpoints + "/200";
}
```

Comment: I should go punish myself, tried all the advanced solutions but not the obvious easy one lol.. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is a issue in your code. You are declaring local variables, which are overwriting the outer ones:

```
function play() {

var myHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 + 1);
var dragonHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 + 1);
```

This should be

```
function play() {

myHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 + 1);
dragonHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40 + 1);
```

To reuse the variables from outside.

Comment: These variables don't need to be reused.